# Is it efficient to use a decorator pattern to define property grid definitions at run time in C# WPF property grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, decorator, propertygrid, xceed

Can you use the decorator pattern to define property definitions for property grids in C# WPF MVVM project?  So I want to implement a specific functionality in a property grid, specifically to be able for the properties to handle changes to its property grid and generate more properties at run-time as a response.

So if someone selects a specific option from a drop down in a property grid, based on the option that was picked, it generates different properties underneath it?  Would using a decorator pattern to define the permutations of different views of the property grid efficient?  Or are there better patterns or methods to handle this type of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The idea sounds quite good when you think about *activating* the additional property rows. The handler would just replace the current `PropertyGrid` instance with a new instance instance of an say `AddiotionalSelection1PropGrid` that wraps the original instance.

However, what happens when you want to *deactivate* additional properties? Do you want to traverse the decorator chain and remove the decorators that should be deactivated? This might become a bit ugly I guess. In order to do this you will have to make the decorateé available to the outside of the decorator. This kind of breaks the decorator pattern, because the decorated instance would not have the same interface as the decoratée has.

A solution to this could be to create an inverse decorator for each decorator that extends the property list. The inverse decorator would just remove all additional properties in case they are present. The inverse decorators solve this problem very elegantly in code, but have some drawbacks:

- It doubles the number of decorators, as for each decorator that adds specific properties there has to be an inverse that removes exactly those properties
- This may lead to very long decorator chains when the user activates/deactivates properties a lot and/or the UI has a long life time. In case they become *really* long it may lead to performance problems. You should take care that each decorator has a minimal memory footprint.

Comment: Yeah, true I did not think about that...  What about a factory pattern to create objects to be sent over to the PropertyGrid.selectedobject and Data Context?  Would that be cleaner?\

Comment: @user3290306, I updated my answer with a suggestion. Can you please check if this sounds reasonable in your scenario?